# Python Pandas: Plotly how to make pie chart have unique colours

Tags: python, pandas, charts, plotly

I have created a pie chart with 15 values included. It displays correctly, apart from some colours are duplicated, making it hard to see what value is linked with the bar chart. See current pie chart below.

[image]

The code used for the pie chart is:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
labels = [ 'Anti-social behaviour', 'Bicycle theft', 'Burglary','Criminal damage and arson', 'Drugs', 'Other crime', 'Other theft', 'Possession of weapons', 'Public order', 'Robbery',
          'Shoplifting', 'Theft from the person', 'Vehicle crime', 'Violence and sexual offences']


sizes = summergroup **<the df**
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes)
plt.legend(patches, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.93,0.93), loc="upper left")



plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to have all the colours on the bar chart unique?

Comment: Is this a matplotlib or plotly question or both?  I wasn't sure, so I've added plotly & matplotlib tags, please delete either of those tags as you see fit.

Comment: Not answering your question but you're probably better off [not using a pie chart here](https://blog.funnel.io/why-we-dont-use-pie-charts-and-some-tips-on-better-data-visualizations). If you really want to do that, I guess you'll have to provide the colors manually ([the docs](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/) contain some examples for that).